# "TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable" with custom slots

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, callable, slots

**The Environment**

I am running an Anaconda environment with Python 3.4. I am using PyCharm as my IDE.

**The Objective**

I am trying to make a pyQt4 QPushButton connect to a custom function:

```
button.clicked().connect([method reference or whatever])
```

**Attempts**

I have tried using the [`pyqtSlot()` decorator](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) but when I run the code it throws:

```
NameError: name 'pyqtSlot' is not defined
```

I have used the following imports which should include that decorator:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

I also attempted to change my method into its own callable class containing a call method.

The general error message that I'm getting for various attempts is this:

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

**The Question**

Honestly, at this point I have pretty much no idea where to go with this or what details you may need to diagnose the problem. Could anyone give me an idea how to put this together?

Comment: If you've imported `QtCore` then use `QtCore.pyqtSlot`. Also, you don't have to call `clicked`, just `button.clicked.connect(some_function)`.

Comment: The `pyqtSlot` decorator is not needed here. Just remove the parentheses from `clicked()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pyqtSlot()` should be imported from `PyQt4.QtCore`:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot
```

it can be also used as `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` since you already import `QtCore`.

You have the error message `TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable` since the slot `clicked` should be connected without parentheses:

```
button.clicked.connect([method reference or whatever])
```

---

You can start from simple examples that you can find in PyQt4 package, for example `examples/widgets/tetrix.py`:

```
    startButton = QtGui.QPushButton("&Start")
    startButton.clicked.connect(self.board.start)
```

Comment: The @QtCore.pyqtSlot() fixed the first bug and removing the parenthesis from 'clicked' fixed the TypeError, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: If using PyQt5    " from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot"

Comment: Hi All - I cannot seem to import pyqtSlot from either PyQt4 or PyQt5 in the ways you both mentioned? It appears to not exist in QtCore??

Answer (score 3):

`object.signal().connect(slot())` should be replaced with `object.signal.connect(slot)`